# Can one person be charged for producing the (inherently dangerous and possibly contraband) murder tool used by someone else?

Tags: murder, manslaughter

If Person A manufactured a poison, and it was given to somebody else by Person B, without Person A's knowledge, what could Person A be charged with?

I am writing a novel for NaNoWriMo and I have set up this situation as a driving force for the mystery. I am just unsure what crime the police could charge Person A with (if not murder, which they suspect he committed).

My first instinct was involuntary manslaughter, but it doesn't seem to fit correctly, and I am unsure how to proceed, as my background is not in law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, making a poison is not in and of itself a crime. If a third party took the poison from the person who manufactured it without their knowledge, the manufacturer would generally not have criminal liability, at least in the absence of "gross criminal negligence" such as leaving the poison manufacturing location totally unsecured and letting people know that there was poison there for the taking.

In a civil case, someone might sue the poison manufacturer for negligently securing their facility, but again, that would be a real stretch if even ordinary precautions (e.g. standard locks on doors and cabinets) were in place, or if it was an inside job theft.

In the same way, a gun store owner is not usually liable criminally or civilly if someone steals a gun from his store and shoots someone with it.

The police could certainly charge Person A with capital murder mistakenly believing him to have intended to kill and did kill someone with the poison, which would make the critical factual point establishing that Person B gave it to someone without Person A's knowledge.

Person A might still be guilty of attempted murder if he intended to kill someone (not necessarily the person who was killed) with the poison but had not fully carried out the plot when the poison was stolen.

Some places probably require a permit of some kind to make poisons, and if Person A didn't have a permit, he could probably also be charged with making poisons without a permit.

Comment: I don't know if a permit is required where I live, I'll have to look into it. In the story, there was no knowledge that it WAS poison, but it was crafted to look like pills, which could have been mistaken for drugs, and one suggestion the main character offered is that Person B (not knowing yet who it was) attempted to use them to drug the deceased. Person A intended to use the poison on himself, but hadn't worked up the courage at the time the pills were used by Person B

Comment: @AuditionMD In those facts there might be civil liability for failure to take reasonable care to clearly label a poison that someone else might mistake for a drug, but that probably wouldn't amount to criminal negligence. In that case, there might be no crime committed at all. The fact that someone dies from a poison does not always mean that there is a crime.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help, I wasn't sure how to proceed otherwise. The novel mostly revolves around Person A trying to prove his own innocence, so your point of the factual point being establishing Person B's theft and use of the poison on another before they can formally charge Person A with capital murder still stands. In the case of Person B, then, he couldn't have possibly known it would result in death, would that then be at the very least involuntary manslaughter?

Comment: @ohwilleke If you try to drug someone without their knowledge or consent, that'd normally be a crime even if they don't die.

Comment: @cpast If you are giving someone medical drugs with the intent to make them healthier, and the person who takes the drugs does so willingly, thinking that they are medicinal (which seems to be the scenario here), the only offense would be providing drugs without a prescription and if the person thought that they were not controlled substances, that would be a pretty minor offense indeed, possibly even only a civil fine.

Comment: @AuditionMD "In the case of Person B, then, he couldn't have possibly known it would result in death, would that then be at the very least involuntary manslaughter?" Almost surely not. Involuntary manslaughter still requires some criminal culpability.

Comment: Well the implied intent in the novel was essentially to get the deceased into a position where Person B could take advantage in some way. Well, that's the running theory of Person A. So the intent was to essentially roofie or otherwise inebriate the deceased.

Comment: I understand the confusion, given my description of the poison, which I will likely have to change to make it more reasonable to believe.

Comment: @ohwilleke I understood “person B drugged the victim” to mean person B thought it was something like roofies, not that person B was trying to give the victim medicine to make them healthier.

Comment: I know of a case where someone kept pesticides in an unlabeled beer bottle (or brandy bottle? I don't remember) in a garden shed, an alcoholic homeless guy broke in, drank it, and died, and the owner was convicted, because of failing to label it that it was poison. I wonder whether a better lawyer could have won his case.